Orientation in Stokes theorem
I'm solving an exercise using Stokes theorem, but I'm not sure if I can solve it correctly.
We have the surface
$$S = \{(u+v,u-v^2,uv) : 0\leq u \leq 1, 0 \leq v\leq 2\}.$$
and the form $\omega = 3z^2dx$. We will get
$$\int_S6uv(v-u)dv \wedge du = 4.$$
The point is that the normal vector is $(u+2v^2,v-u,-2v-1)$ and I don't know what it says about the orientation.

All I can say is that this is your surface and that the normal vector obviously points downward, that is, its $z$-component is always negative. Another thing is that that $0$-form $\omega=3z^2$ looks unrelated to the integral.

I think what you wanted was $\omega=3(uv)^2(du+dv)$ which gives your integral as $\int_S,d\omega,.$

@KurtG.I corrected the differential form
